# How to pass variables onto another function?

Tags: c, function, variables

I'm not sure how to pass on the variables from main() to another function.
I have something like this:

```
main()
{
  float a, b, c;

  printf("Enter the values of 'a','b' and 'c':");
  scanf("%f %f %f",&a,&b,&c);
}

double my_function(float a,float b,float c)
{
  double d;

      d=a+b+c
      bla bla bla bla
```

How can I pass a, b and c from main to my_function? For now the program stops on scanf() and finishes straight after I put my values in.

I've seen different examples here but they didn't help me much.

Comment: You should check `scanf()`'s return value before relying on the variables having new values.

Comment: If stops on `scanf` because that function waits for the input to be done. The program exits after `scanf` because there is no more statements to execute. And about calling a function with arguments, that's what you already do with `printf` and `scanf`, just call your own function with the correct arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call the function by passing the parameters `a`, `b`, and `c`.  Syntax:

```
retval = function_name(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3); //pass parameters as required
```

Like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    float a, b, c;
    double d;

    printf("Enter the values of 'a','b' and 'c': ");
    if (scanf("%f %f %f",&a,&b,&c) == 3)
    {
        d = my_function(a, b, c);
        printf("Result: %f\n", d);
    }
    else
        printf("Oops: I didn't understand what you typed\n");      
}
```

Comment: This is what I was missing. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Function call.

```
my_function(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the function from main !

```
float my_function(float a,float b,float c)
{
  float d;

  d=a+b+c;
  return d ;
}

int main()
{
  float a, b, c;
  float result ;

  printf("Enter the values of 'a','b' and 'c':");
  scanf("%f %f %f",&a,&b,&c);

  result = my_function(a,b,c);
  printf("\nResult is %f", result );    

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1: Nice work.  Ideally, you'd test that the input was received correctly.  Your rewrite ensures that the function definition is in scope before it is used, satisfying C99.  I'd prefer to see an explicit `int main(void)` (the `int` at least is necessary for C99).

Comment: cool, nice info! Edited my reply too to add int before main.